# Pandas to parse the text data and aligned the columns based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have  below text data which i need to parse and split into columns based on below condition..

1. anything that starts with `=` should come under `ENC_NAME`
2. any line that contains `BladeSystem`, number at the end of line should come under column `OA_VERSION`
3. any line that contains `1 HP` should come under column `VC_ACTIVE`
4. any line that contains `2 HP` should come under column `VC_STDN`

### text data

```
========= enc1001 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1002 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1003 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1004 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1005 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1006 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1007 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1008 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.40
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.40
========= enc1009 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2001 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2002 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2003 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2004 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2005 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2006 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2007 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2008 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2009 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2011 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2013 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc3020 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
========= enc3021 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
========= enc3022 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
========= enc3026 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.45
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.45
========= enc3027 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc3028 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc3029 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc3030 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc3031 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc4021 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
========= enc4023 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
========= enc4024 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
========= enc4025 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
========= enc4026 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc4027 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc4028 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc4029 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc4030 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc4031 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc4032 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc4033 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc4034 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc6002 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.60
========= enc6011 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.60
========= enc6012 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.60
========= enc6013 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.60
========= enc6014 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.60
========= enc6015 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.60
========= enc6016 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.60
========= enc6017 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.60
========= enc7002 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
========= enc7003 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
========= enc7004 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
========= enc7009 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1010 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1011 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1012 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1013 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1014 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1015 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1016 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1017 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1018 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc1025 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
========= enc1026 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2010 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2012 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2014 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2015 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2016 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2018 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2019 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2020 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2021 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2022 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc2023 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc3033 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc3034 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc3036 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc4020 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
========= enc4022 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.41
========= enc4035 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc7005 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc7006 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC FlexFabric 10Gb/24-Port Module  4.50
  2 HP VC FlexFabric 10Gb/24-Port Module  4.50
========= enc7007 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
========= enc7008 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
========= enc8001 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc8017 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc8018 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc8019 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc8021 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.50
========= enc8022 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
========= enc8023 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
========= enc8024 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
========= enc8025 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
========= enc8026 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
========= enc8027 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
========= enc8028 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.62
========= enc8033 =========
1   BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM 4.85
  1 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.40
  2 HP VC Flex-10/10D Module   4.40
```

### Desired Output(example):

```
ENC_NAME    OA_VERSION      VC_ACTIVE   VC_STDN
enc4031     4.85            4.50        4.50
enc4032     4.85            4.50        4.50
enc4033     4.85            4.50        4.50
enc4034     4.85            4.50        4.50
enc6002     4.60            NaN         NaN
enc6011     4.60            NaN         NaN
enc6012     4.60            NaN         NaN
enc6013     4.60            NaN         NaN
```

### EDIT(What i tried)

```
df  = pd.read_csv("enc_list_sorted", names=["col1"])
df = df.col1.str.split(' ', expand = True)
df = df.drop(df.columns[[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11]], axis=1)


df = df.rename(columns={ 1: 'ENC_NAME', 9: 'VC_VERSION', 10: 'OA_VERSION'})

print(df)

        ENC_NAME VC_VERSION OA_VERSION
    0    enc1001       None       None
    1                   KVM       4.85
    2                  4.50       None
    3                  4.50       None
    4    enc1002       None       None
    5                   KVM       4.85
    6                  4.50       None
    7                  4.50       None
    8    enc1003       None       None
    9                   KVM       4.85
    10                 4.50       None
    11                 4.50       None
    12   enc1004       None       None
    13                  KVM       4.85
    14                 4.50       None
    15                 4.50       None
```

any help or idea would be very helpful .

Comment: Use a parser instead.

Comment: @Jan, thanks for the input , do you mean creating python parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in comments here open the file with `pandas` and parse is not ideal.

Let says your data is saved on a text file `file.txt`

```py
import pandas as pd

with open("file.txt") as file:
    lines = [l.rstrip("\n") for l in file]


row_temp = [None] * 4
row = None
out = []
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith("="):
        if row is not None:
            out.append(row)
        row = row_temp.copy()
        row[0] = line.replace("=", "").rstrip().lstrip()

    if 'BladeSystem' in line:
        row[1] = line.split(" ")[-1]
    if '1 HP' in line:
        row[2] = line.split(" ")[-1]
    if '2 HP' in line:
        row[3] = line.split(" ")[-1]

col_names = ["ENC_NAME", "OA_VERSION", "VC_ACTIVE", "VC_STDN"]
df = pd.DataFrame(out,
                  columns=col_names)
```

returns the output you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks so much @rpanai, i will try that +1

Comment: If i am applying it to the large dataset then its not printing the value of  `OA_VERSION` column.

Comment: Is this happening for every block?

Comment: Yes, for the entire column there is no data and also skipping the last data of the file.

Comment: I have Just added the text dataset on the post.

Comment: I see there was space which was causing issue, which i fixed and it works but only the problem is it does not take the last block of the data ie `enc8033`

Comment: My bad, for the last block of data you should add `out.append(row)` outside the loop.

Comment: Ok, thanks.. would appreciate if you could explain about `row_temp = [None] * 4`  and 
`row = None`

Comment: No problems. It's just a trick to add a new line every new block starting with `=` I fix the size of the list so if there are not entries (as for enc6002 ) it still return a list of len 4. row=None so we don't append on the first step on the loop. Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, use a self-written parser instead. What you have can be seen as a form of a so called DSL, a domain specific language. The grammar used here is rather forgiving:

```
import re, pandas as pd
from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar
from parsimonious.nodes import NodeVisitor

class ENCVisitor(NodeVisitor):
    grammar = Grammar(r"""
            content     = (ws / block)*

            block       = header oa_line vc_active? vc_stdn?
            header      = delim ws word ws delim nl

            oa_line     = ~"^(?=.*BladeSystem).+"m nl?
            vc_active   = ~"^(?=.*1 HP).+"m nl?
            vc_stdn     = ~"^(?=.*2 HP).+"m nl?

            word        = ~"\w+"
            delim       = ~"=+"
            ws          = ~"\s+"
            nl          = ~"[\n\r]+"
    """)

    version_pattern = re.compile(r"\d+\.\d+$")

    def get_version(self, key, line):
        match = self.version_pattern.search(line)
        value = match.group(0) if match else None
        return {key: value}

    def generic_visit(self, node, visited_children):
        return visited_children or node

    def visit_header(self, node, visited_children):
        header = visited_children[2]
        return {"ENC_NAME": header.text}

    def visit_oa_line(self, node, visited_children):
        line, _ = visited_children
        return self.get_version("OA_VERSION", line.text)

    def visit_vc_active(self, node, visited_children):
        line, _ = visited_children
        return self.get_version("VC_ACTIVE", line.text)

    def visit_vc_stdn(self, node, visited_children):
        line, _ = visited_children
        return self.get_version("VC_STDN", line.text)

    def visit_block(self, node, visited_children):
        dct = {}
        for child in visited_children:
            if isinstance(child, dict):
                dct.update(child)
            elif isinstance(child, list):
                dct.update(child[0])
        return dct

    def visit_content(self, node, visited_children):
        return [child[0] for child in visited_children if isinstance(child[0], dict)]

enc = ENCVisitor()
result = enc.parse(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(result)
print(df)
```

For your data give, this results in

```
   ENC_NAME OA_VERSION VC_ACTIVE VC_STDN
0   enc1001       4.85      4.50    4.50
1   enc1002       4.85      4.50    4.50
2   enc1003       4.85      4.50    4.50
3   enc1004       4.85      4.50    4.50
4   enc1005       4.85      4.50    4.50
..      ...        ...       ...     ...
94  enc8025       4.85      4.62    4.62
95  enc8026       4.85      4.62    4.62
96  enc8027       4.85      4.62    4.62
97  enc8028       4.85      4.62    4.62
98  enc8033       4.85      4.40    4.40

[99 rows x 4 columns]
```

---

**Explanation**: Your input can be seen as sort of an own mini language, a so called domain specific language. Each block of information in your file consists of a header line, an `OA_VERSION` line and two lines that may or may not be there (`VC_ACTIVE` and `VC_STDN`). Your header line always starts and ends with `===`.

All of these bricks form a grammar, that is whitespaces or multiple blocks in your file / string. Internally, we build up an abstract syntrax tree (*ast*) and to retrieve the information, we need to "visit" each node. In the parser library I chose to use (the excellent `parsimonious`), this is done via a `NodeVisitor` class and each leaf of the ast is visited via the corresponding function name. Meaning if we call a part "header", the function should be named "visit_header".

The result is fetched via "visit_block" and is a dictionary of all the retrieved information of this block. In the end everything is fed into `pandas`.

Of course, this can only be a short introduction, if you want to read more about `parsimonious`, have a look at the [**Github repository**](https://github.com/erikrose/parsimonious).

Comment: Jan, thanks a mile for producing your version of solution, +1 for the same, yes ... indeed would appreciate if you could explain.

Comment: Many thanks for explaining at length, have a great Day.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import numpy as np

with open(r'test1.txt','r') as file:
    txto=file.read()

data=[]
pattern1 = re.compile('(^\=.+)\s.+$\n?', re.MULTILINE)
lstlines=txto.split('\n')

for ele1, ele2 in zip(re.findall(pattern1,txto),re.findall(pattern1,txto)[1:]):
    row=lstlines[lstlines.index(ele1):lstlines.index(ele2)]

    OA_VERSION=[i for i in row if 'BladeSystem' in i]
    OA_VERSION=OA_VERSION[0].split()[-1] if len(OA_VERSION)>0 else np.nan
    
    VC_ACTIVE=[i for i in row if '1 HP' in i]
    VC_ACTIVE=VC_ACTIVE[0].split()[-1] if len(VC_ACTIVE)>0 else np.nan
    
    VC_STDN=[i for i in row if '2 HP' in i]
    VC_STDN=VC_STDN[0].split()[-1] if len(VC_STDN)>0 else np.nan
    
    data.append([ele1.replace('=','').strip(),OA_VERSION, VC_ACTIVE,VC_STDN])
    
#last row 
row=lstlines[lstlines.index(re.findall(pattern1,txto)[-1]):]
OA_VERSION=[i for i in row if 'BladeSystem' in i]
OA_VERSION=OA_VERSION[0].split()[-1] if len(OA_VERSION)>0 else np.nan
VC_ACTIVE=[i for i in row if '1 HP' in i]
VC_ACTIVE=VC_ACTIVE[0].split()[-1] if len(VC_ACTIVE)>0 else np.nan
VC_STDN=[i for i in row if '2 HP' in i]
VC_STDN=VC_STDN[0].split()[-1] if len(VC_STDN)>0 else np.nan
data.append([re.findall(pattern1,txto)[-1].replace('=','').strip(),OA_VERSION, VC_ACTIVE,VC_STDN]) 

#Create dataframe
df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ENC_NAME ','OA_VERSION','VC_ACTIVE','VC_STDN'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
df
   ENC_NAME  OA_VERSION VC_ACTIVE VC_STDN
0    enc1001       4.85      4.50    4.50
1    enc1002       4.85      4.50    4.50
2    enc1003       4.85      4.50    4.50
3    enc1004       4.85      4.50    4.50
4    enc1005       4.85      4.50    4.50
..       ...        ...       ...     ...
94   enc8025       4.85      4.62    4.62
95   enc8026       4.85      4.62    4.62
96   enc8027       4.85      4.62    4.62
97   enc8028       4.85      4.62    4.62
98   enc8033       4.85      4.40    4.40

[99 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks so much @MrNobody33, i will try that +1

Comment: Can you please edit it how to do it by reading the data from file.

Comment: Same problem on the test dataset as provied, its working fine but with larger dataset of same type its giving wrong results. I have Just uploaded the actual dataset.